# How to draw the lines or edges of a cone in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to draw the lines or the edges of a cone using plot3 in matlab. Any help please? I do not need the surface. I need the edges only. SO that I can patch something on it. A useful link. But i need the circle at the bottom: 
https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US8514658B2/US08514658-20130820-D00021.png

Few horizontal lines are fine. But no tilted line as i need to patch something inside.

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE PLEASE READ CAREFULLY.

Comment: I realized that. If you strictly want to use `plot3` then this is not a strict duplicate. I was going to retract my vote but another "gold-badge" member marked it as duplicate. So it got closed. I have voted it for re-opening.

Comment: Is there anyone there. Forcing it to be duplicate...

Comment: I do not need the SURFACE

Comment: I need the LINES only

Comment: If you are not hell-bent on using `plot3`, the linked answer works by making a minor modification. Here is the code: `t = [0;1];
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(t);
surf(X,Y,Z);
alpha(0)`

Comment: Yes, I get all the lines vertical, I do not want them. I want the Edges only not surf.

Comment: I get a proper cone. Only edges, no surface, that's what you wanted, right? Also, I get proper tilted lines as they should be in a cone. No vertical lines.

Comment: @Creator - I've reopened it.  You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Most of the answer is directly taken from the above answer by @RTL.

```
numRings = 2;
numPointsAround = 100;
[x,y,z] = cylinder(linspace(-1,0,numRings),numPointsAround);
plot3(y.',x.',z.','-k')
hold on;line([-0.5878;0], [0.809;0],[0;1]);
hold on;line([0.9511;0], [-0.309;0],[0;1]);
axis square
```

Answer (score 3):

[`cylinder`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cylinder.html) is your friend here...
You just need to pass it a vector of radii* and transpose the output*...

* negative radii tending to zero will flip the order so the apex is on top...
* so it draws rings not lines from the base to the apex

```
numRings = 10;
numPointsAround = 100;

[x,y,z] = cylinder(linspace(-1,0,nlines),numPointsAround);
plot3(y.',x.',z.','-k')
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It might help me, but actually I need the circle at the bottom and the side two straight line. It is like looking at the cone from back or front. Couple of circle in the whole cone may be fine but not so many. Thank you anyway, I will mark it as correct answer so that you will get points. But can you help me to do what I want.

Comment: @RTL I think you meant `numRings` instead of `nlines`.